# Calling Variable Not Working

Tags: jquery, variables, counter, setinterval

Trying to make a small counting app, you can see it here:

http://codepen.io/rossdw/pen/ioHvq

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){

  x = 0;

$('.post').each(function(){


var counter = $(this).find('.counter').html();

var counternumber = parseInt(counter);

var x = x+counternumber;

console.log(x);

$(this).children('.output').html(x);
});
},1000);
});
```

Basically every second, that .each function should add the number in .counter to x, which starts at 0. For example, the first number should read 10 then 20 then 30 etc.

var counter takes the string in .counter, var counternumber takes the actual number with parseInt, var x takes the first var x which equals 0, then adds that counternumber to it. It's then placed in .output. This happens every second.

The issue is this, when var x is a local variable inside the .each function, it sees x as 0 every second, so outputs the same number. When it's a global variable outside of this, it returns as NaN. What I want is for it to see x as 0 the first time, add counternumber, then in the next second use the new x.

Any ideas?

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: May the code be with you...

Comment: In order to store data in global context (so e.g. it persists individual function calls) consider to place it in the global scope => global variable; declare it before yo use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable in the scope you want to have it defined, i.e. covering your timer updates:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var x = 0;

 setInterval(function(){

  $('.post').each(function(){
   var counter = $(this).find('.counter').text();
   var counternumber = parseInt(counter);
   x += counternumber;
   console.log(x);
   $(this).children('.output').text(x);
  });
 },1000);
});
```